# How to get extra headers sent along with emails Amazon SES SMTP through SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

How do you **receive back headers (metadata)** initially sent **with an email message through SMTP (Amazon SES)**.

I've setup the SNS service to call my url correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile Amazon introduced this feature, in July:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/amazon-ses-now-includes-original-message-headers-in-notifications/